# Setting CustomBuild's OutputItemType in a target doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-target

If you set "Add Outputs to Item Type" property in Custom Build Tool like this,

[image: Add outputs to item type]

It will add the following line in `.vcxproj` file:

```xml
<OutputItemType>ClCompile</OutputItemType>
```

However, when I define my own target and try to use it, it doesn't work.

```xml
(...)

<Target Name="__SECompile" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">

    <ItemGroup>
        <_SECompileMetadataSet Include="@(SECompile)">
            <Message>Processing %(Identity)</Message>
            <Outputs>$(ProjectDir)intermediate\%(Identity)</Outputs>
            <Command>python (path to a python script) "%(FullPath)" "$(ProjectDir)intermediate\%(Identity)"</Command>
            <OutputItemType>ClCompile</OutputItemType>
            <LinkObjects>false</LinkObjects>
        </_SECompileMetadataSet>
    </ItemGroup>

(...)
(Below is just a copy-paste from Microsoft.CppCommon.targets)

    <!-- Get out of date items (will create tlogs for all SECompile items) -->
    <GetOutOfDateItems
      Condition                 ="'$(SelectedFiles)' == ''"
      Sources                   ="@(_SECompileMetadataSet)"
      OutputsMetadataName       ="Outputs"
      DependenciesMetadataName  ="AdditionalInputs"
      CommandMetadataName       ="Command"
      TLogDirectory             ="$(TLogLocation)"
      TLogNamePrefix            ="SECompile"
      CheckForInterdependencies ="true"
      >
      <Output TaskParameter="OutOfDateSources" ItemName="_SECompile"/>
    </GetOutOfDateItems>

    <!-- Buidl items which can be built in parallel (ignored for selected files build)-->
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(SelectedFiles)' == ''">
      <_ParallelSECompile Include="@(_SECompile)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ParallelCustomBuild
      Condition       ="'@(_ParallelSECompile)' != ''"
      Sources         ="@(_ParallelSECompile)"
      MaxProcesses    ="0"
      MaxItemsInBatch ="0"
      AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes  =""
    />

(...)
```

The python script is running and the message is being output, so the other properties are functioning. But `OutputItemType` doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is basically do the exact same thing `CustomBuild` does, with its arguments predefined with specific values.

**So the question is**:
Why doesn't it work when you set it manually in a target while it should be the same as it was set in the `vcxproj` file?

Comment: Maybe you can try to add it into [ItemMetadata group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemmetadata-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT Yep, I forgot to update, I already tried that after posting this question. Doesn't work either.

Comment: You can try to move the ItemGroup out of Target

Comment: @DylanZhu-MSFT Thanks for suggesting. However, that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer through Visual Studio Feedback.
Putting

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'@(_SECompile)' != ''"> <ClCompile Include="%(_SECompile.Outputs)" Condition="'%(_SECompile.ExcludedFromBuild)' != 'true'" /> </ItemGroup>
```

in the target would work.

Original link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Setting-CustomBuilds-OutputItemType-in/1452940?entry=myfeedback&ref=native&refTime=1624191549072&refUserId=95d48ba8-b75f-4896-8bf5-5745bf012b77